# I can´t turn on Bluetooth in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

I have recently bought a cheap usb dongle and I cannot get bluetooth to work. My motherboard did not have any bluetooth out of the box. This is what I got after typing sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth

```
[    4.852334] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.852354] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    4.852356] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.852358] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.852360] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.852364] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.050444] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[    5.050450] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Failed to suspend the device for our Barrot 8041a02 receive-issue workaround
[   15.995094] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   15.995098] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   15.995102] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

I have seen many of the questions similar to mine but they have different initial situations with this command.

When I try: `sudo hciconfig hci0 up` it says:

```
Can't init device hci0: Invalid argument (22)
```

When I try `sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service I get that the service is active and runnning, yet in the settings GUI it shows as turned off.

Comment: Buy a normal dongle. This is not supported.

Comment: a tp-link one would suffice? I used a CSR previously

Comment: It depends on chipset but on a brand.